# Need help in C printf formatted output

Tags: c, printf

I am displaying a partition table, and the table is displayed somewhat like:

```
Number     Device name       Partition type      Size in MB
------------------------------------------------------------
1           /dev/sda1         NTFS                    300
2           /dev/sda2         *Win95 FAT32             99
3           /dev/sda3         Unknown                 128
4           /dev/sda4         NTFS                  19472
120         /dev/sda120       NTFS                   3000

*=Active partition
```

Now for displaying the above, we are using formatted output printf and the format string is

```
"%-6d=partition number    %-25.25s=device name  %c=active partition    %-30.30s=part type          %7Ld=size"
```

Now i want to display the same partition table, but with some slight modification, such that the gaps in partition slots would be displayed by a range, like:

```
5-119     /dev/sda5.../dev/sda119    Empty          0
```

I am using the formatted string as:

```
%d-%-6d=partition range   %s%d...%s%d=(/dev/sda5.../dev/sda119)   %c  %-30.30s  %7Ld
```

but it does not help me.

What should be the correct format string? I am using a gcc compiler.

Comment: what is the output of the last format ?

Comment: So what kind of output do you get with `%d-%-6d   %s%d...%s%d   %c  %-30.30s  %7Ld` then, how is it wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to use `snprintf()` to prepare the two composite strings, and then a simpler `printf()` to do the actual printing.  Since you've not shown your actual code, we have to guess at everything, which is a nuisance...

```
int   min = 5;
int   max = 119;
char *dev = "/dev/sda";

char  num_range[32];
char  dev_range[60];

snprintf(num_range, sizeof(num_range), "%d-%d", min, max);
snprintf(dev_range, sizeof(dev_range), "%s%d...%s%d", dev, min, dev, max);

printf("%-10s   %-50.50s   %c%-30.30s  %7d", num_range, dev_range, ' ', "Empty", 0);
```

You specified `%-25.25s` for a single device, so it isn't clear whether you should double that for the range, or you should use some other value (or even the same value); you'll need to tweak that part of the format string to suit yourself.  This technique is also how I get a colon at the end of a name — format the name and the colon into a string, and then format that string into the final print operation.

Comment: Earlier a device was shows by a single string, like `/dev/sda5` is one string. But now the dev name part and the partition part are string and numeral, as we are calculating the gap. Like /dev/sda is a string and 5 is a numeral. Please let me know if you need more clarification.

Comment: The `dev_range` string ends up with `/dev/sda5.../dev/sda119` (23 characters); the only issue is how much space to use for that in the final `printf()`. Should it be 50 (as in the answer at the moment), or 25 (as in the original), or some other value? Should it be printed with `%-25s` so it takes up at least that much space, but if the names are longer (`/dev/rdsk/c1d0s2t0.../dev/rdsk/c1d0s2t6`) then it shunts the other data over without losing any information (just alignment). Ultimately, that's a trivial detail you can change to suit yourself. The key point is using pre-formatted strings.

Comment: Thanks for the help, with your suggested snprintf and adjusting both the original and my formatted string i got it aligned. Original i made: `"%-8d %-27.25s%c%-32.30s%7Ld"` and for my partition range display: `"%-7s  %-25.50s  %c%-30.30s  %7Ld\n"` Using both in conjunction gives an aligned output :)